# PowerBI - Amount from multiple columns for one value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a list of projects and what Systems they require.
Because it is possible for one project to have multiple systems we used multiple columns for this information.
Now i want to calculate the amount of "Local Ownerships" in all Columns.

For excample:

| Project Name | System 1 ownership | System 2 ownership | System 3 ownership |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Local Ownership | Local Ownership | empty |
| Project 2 | Central Ownership | empty | empty |
| Project 3 | Central Ownerhip | Central Onwnership | Local Ownership |

Local Ownership (#): 3

The values can be either `Local Ownership` or `Central Ownership`

Comment: If you want to do this with DAX then you'll need to create a separate expression for each column. Would strongly suggest unpivoting those columns in Power Query first, after which you'll have a single column containing all ownerships and therefore only a single DAX formula required.

Answer (score 0):

For this [Unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column) the table using System columns and get a count on "Local Ownership" or "Central Ownership" columns according to the requirement.

Comment: So the problem is that those values come from a system export and were formated like this. I need a method that won't require manual labor because it can change with every export. If I create a new Table with your approach i have to edit it after every update.

Comment: @shmeonyou Not really if you can update the same source with new records this will be one time thing.Source data is in a csv?